# Redirecting user values from one template to another - Django

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Trying to redirect the values ​​given by the user from one page to the next. 
Everything can be done in one view, but when I try to redirect to the next one using HttpResponseRedirect Django return error 'NameError at /search_results, name '' is not defined'. How to pass the 'text' value from one view to another (to my search results)

**My views.py (Works well, the values ​​given by the user in one field, return the corresponding results of the cure from django-filters)**

```
def test_views(request):
    form = MeanForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        text = form.cleaned_data['name']
    else:
        text = None
    search_users = SearchWoman(request.GET, queryset=Woman.objects.all().filter(city=text))

    context = { 'form': form, 'text': text, 'filter': search_users }
    return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

**My test.html**

```
<h1>TEST_1</h1>
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

<h2> {{ text }}  </h2>

<h1><br></br></h1>

{% for profile in filter.qs %}
<li>{{ profile.name }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**My filters.py**

```
from .models import Woman
import django_filters

class SearchWoman(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Woman
        fields = ['city', 'rating']
```

**My forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Mean

class MeanForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Mean
        fields = ('name',)
```

**How I try to do a redirect (it returns error "NameError at / search_results, nazwa" "is not defined")**

```
def test_views(request):
    form = MeanForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        text = form.cleaned_data['name']
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/search_results/')
    else:
        text = None

    context = { 'form': form, 'text': text, }
    return render(request, 'test.html', context)

def search_results(request):
    search_users = SearchWoman(request.GET, queryset=Woman.objects.all().filter(city=text))
    context = { 'search_user': search_users }
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)
```

**Tempaltes Error (after applying the second view)**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search_results/

Django Version: 2.1.3
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'host_app',
 'django_filters']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\agencja_modeli_modelek\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\agencja_modeli_modelek\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\agencja_modeli_modelek\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\agencja_modeli_modelek\app_rama\host_app\views.py" in search_results
  59.     search_users = SearchWoman(request.GET, queryset=Woman.objects.all().filter(city=text))

Exception Type: NameError at /search_results/
Exception Value: name 'text' is not defined
```

**EDIT: error code: **

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/

Django Version: 2.1.3
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'host_app',
 'django_filters']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\agencja_modeli_modelek\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\agencja_modeli_modelek\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\agencja_modeli_modelek\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\agencja_modeli_modelek\app_rama\host_app\views.py" in test_views
  50.         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('search_results', args=[text]))

File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\agencja_modeli_modelek\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\agencja_modeli_modelek\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  622.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /test/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'search_results' not found. 'search_results' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

**URLS App**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views


app_name = 'host_app'

urlpatterns = [
    [...]
    url(r'^test/$', views.test_views, name='test_views'),
    url(r'^search_results/(?P<text>[\w\-]+)/$', views.search_results, name='search_results')
]
```

**URLS Rama (next to settings.py**)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('host_app.urls', namespace='host_app')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback for the error. Where are you using `nazwa`? Do you mean `text`? You can pass that either by including it in the url as a query parameter `https://example.com/search_results/?text=foobar` or by stashing the value in the session object. [django docs: How to use sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/) `request.session['text'] = 'foobar'`

Comment: Yes, I meant the text, I'm sorry for the mistake. The full description of the error is now added to the main comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using django-filters, it would make sense to put the data in the query parameters of the redirect.

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def test_views(request):
    city, rating = 'Springfield', 11  # or get them from a form
    query_string = urlencode({'city': city, 'rating': rating})
    next_url = '{}?{}'.format(reverse(search_results), query_string)
    return HttpResonseRedirect(next_url)


def search_results(request):
    search_users = SearchWoman(request.GET)
    # when redirected, the url and request.GET contains data from previous view
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'search_users': search_users})
```

Another way to pass data is to use the session object. This requires that django's session middleware is active and the client uses cookies. Both are standard, so it should work well for a typical web site.

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def test_views(request):
    city = 'Springfield'
    request.session['city'] = city  # set session['city']
    return HttpResonseRedirect(reverse(search_results)


def search_results(request):
    city = request.session.get('city')  # get session['city']
    data = request.GET.dict()  # get url query parameters if any
    if city:
       data['city'] = city
    search_users = SearchWoman(data)
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'search_users': search_users})
```

Sessions are easy to use. If you want to learn more about how sessions work, read this section of the django docs: [How to use sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/)

Comment: Thank you, your answer is extremely useful, but how do you use it for the checkbox? We have the Citi class, and in the middle of it defined 'def __str__ (self): return self.name_city' well we can see in the '/admin': London, Warsaw, Prague, etc. after setting in the view.py city = 'London', the redirection is not entered in django filters. We cen see only 'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.' 
How to relate to it properly? do I define something else in models.py?

Comment: You have to make sure the data you pass in to the form is valid. For example, in my answer I use a string for "city", but if city is a foreign key field, you must use the city's id instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this with [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) to send parameters to next view:

```
# views
def test_views(request):
    form = MeanForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        text = form.cleaned_data['name']
        eturn HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('search_result', args=[text]))
    else:
        text = None

    context = { 'form': form, 'text': text, }
    return render(request, 'test.html', context)

def search_results(request, text):
    search_users = SearchWoman(request.GET, queryset=Woman.objects.all().filter(city=text))
    context = { 'search_user': search_users }
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)

# urls
path('search_result/<str:text>/', search_results, name="search_result")

# urls for django 1.11 or older versions
url(r'^search_result/(?P<text>[\w\-]+)/$',search_results, name="search_result")
```

Comment: The documentation looks interesting, thank you for your answer. But so far I am getting a mistake from the template.    ` NoReverseMatch at /test/
Reverse for '/search_results/' not found. '/search_results/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` My files after changes in the comment below. Did I write something wrong?

Comment: In the urls, there is a parameter called `name`, resolve actually uses this to reverse find your actual url path. So, first you need to update that in the views and the urls. If still reverse throws a problem, then please post the traceback with the original question.

Comment: I try to implement your solution, but the template still returns the same error (after entering the value in the search engine). Full description of the error above.

Comment: @MaddieGraham can you add your url structures please? (also please include `urls.py` which resides beside `settings.py`)

Comment: I added my urls files (my app and my rama). You also wrote: 'eturn HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('search_result', args=[text]))', my line of this code looks like this: 'return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/search_results/', args=[text]))' I added '/' without this 'HttpResponseRedirect' did not redirect.

Comment: please try with `reverse('host_app:search_result', args=[text])`

Comment: the answer works in part. My urls address changes to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/search_results/inside_search/'. But the template still returns an error 'TypeError at /search_results/inside_search/
search_results() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text''

Comment: please see my answer, where I have updated the view code.

Comment: Everything is working properly. Thank you very much for help.